# Is there a way to change the title of an html page while it opens an xml file?

Tags: html, xml

I have an xml file called `file.xml`, I want to know how to change the title of the html page that xml file is open in.
For example, if I have the following link in my html file: `<a href="file.xml">Link</a>`. When I click on that link, the page title is `root/file.xml`, is there a way to change it? How can I change the title tag `<title></title>` in that webpage so when I open the xml file in the browser the title is there.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

It will not popup in a snippet but try it on a server

https://plungjan.name/SO/framewindow/

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("link")) {
    const w = window.open("", "_blank");
    if (w) { // popup not blocked
      const html = `<title>${tgt.title}</title><body style="margin:0; padding:0"><iframe style="height:100%; width:100%; border:0" src="${tgt.href}"></iframe></body>`
      e.preventDefault();
      w.document.write(html);
      w.document.close();
    }
    // else let the link work on its own
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="link" title="File #1" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=file1.xml">File1.xml</a>
  <a class="link" title="File #2" href="https://www.google.com/search?q=file2.xml">File2.xml</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran the code on local host, but it didn't work.

Comment: Typo. I forgot to close the body tag. See https://plungjan.name/SO/framewindow/